# How to auto generate all phpdoc comments for a specific custom class?

Tags: php, phpdoc

[This github file](https://github.com/CarbonPHP/carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php) contains this auto-generated phpdoc comment

```
/**
 * ...
 * <autodoc generated by `composer phpdoc`>
 *
 * @property      int                 $year
 * @property      int                 $yearIso
 * @property      int                 $month
 * ...
*/
```

I try to install phpdoc(not with composer), and to execute it, but it generate a documentation outside of the file(it does not write any comments). How can I auto-generate a phpdoc comment for a specific class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the [phpDocumentor project](https://www.phpdoc.org/3.0/) with something custom that resides within the Carbon repo. The custom composer script/command adds a docblock to all methods, while phpDocumentor generates a documentation site based on *existing* docblocks.

The command `composer phpdoc` is an alias that is defined within the `composer.json` file of the repository:

```json
"scripts": {
    "phpdoc": "php phpdoc.php"
    
    ... more scripts
}
```

The command runs [this file](https://github.com/CarbonPHP/carbon/blob/master/phpdoc.php) in the repository, which essentially loops over all the methods and adds a docblock to the all methods:

```php
foreach ($factories as $file => $methods) {
    $autoDoc = compileDoc($methods, $file);
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $files->$file = preg_replace_callback('/(<autodoc[\s\S]*>)([\s\S]+)(<\/autodoc>)/mU', function ($matches) use ($file, $autoDoc) {
        return $matches[1]."\n *$autoDoc\n *\n * ".$matches[3];
    }, $content, 1);
}

foreach ($files as $file => $contents) {
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```